# Apache Spark - Does dataset.dropDuplicates() preserve partitioning?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know that there exist several transformations which preserve parent partitioning (if it was set before - e.g. `mapValues`) and some which do not preserve it (e.g. `map`).

I use Dataset API of Spark 2.2. My question is - does `dropDuplicates` transformation preserve partitioning? Imagine this code:

```
case class Item(one: Int, two: Int, three: Int)

import session.implicits._
val ds = session.createDataset(List(Item(1,2,3), Item(1,2,3)))

val repart = ds.repartition('one, 'two).cache()

repart.dropDuplicates(List("one", "two")) // will be partitioning preserved?
```

Comment: note that `ds.dropDuplicates` returns a new dataset, so you should assign it to a new variable

Comment: why do you think `map` will not preserve partitioning? I'm pretty sure it does (because its a narrow transformation)

Comment: What does it mean to preserve partitioning? To me it's equivalent with "there will be no implicit shuffling" and `map` doesn't cause shuffling. On the other hand, if one used it's own partitioning (hash based or whatever) and he changes the keys with `map`, it'll be no more "valid" according to the partitioner, but afaik no shuffle is invoked... that's probably why `mapValues` is even more safer, because it can't change keys that contribute to partitioner.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth - I wasn't much clear I think - now I realized that yes, I guess partitioning will be preserved with `map`, but "partitioner" (hash, range) will not because if you have e.g.:  `repart.map(_ => "Hello")` the columns `'one, 'two` will be lost and the previous partitioning won't have sense anymore.

Comment: @JiriKremser exactly as you say... I think I should use word "partitioner" instead of "partitioning"... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

generally, `dropDuplicates` does a shuffle (and thus not preserve partitioning), but in your special case it does NOT do an additional shuffle because you have already partitioned the dataset in a suitable form which is taken into account by the optimizer:

```
repart.dropDuplicates(List("one","two")).explain()

 == Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[one#3, two#4, three#5], functions=[])
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[one#3, two#4, three#5], functions=[])
   +- InMemoryTableScan [one#3, two#4, three#5]
         +- InMemoryRelation [one#3, two#4, three#5], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(one#3, two#4, 200)
                  +- LocalTableScan [one#3, two#4, three#5]
```

the keyword to look for here is : `Exchange`

But consider the following code where you first repartition the dataset using plain `repartition()`:

```
val repart = ds.repartition(200).cache()
repart.dropDuplicates(List("one","two")).explain()
```

This will indeed trigger an additional shuffle ( now you have 2 `Exchange` steps):

```
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[one#3, two#4], functions=[first(three#5, false)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(one#3, two#4, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[one#3, two#4], functions=[partial_first(three#5, false)])
      +- InMemoryTableScan [one#3, two#4, three#5]
            +- InMemoryRelation [one#3, two#4, three#5], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                  +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(200)
                     +- LocalTableScan [one#3, two#4, three#5]
```

NOTE: I checked that with Spark 2.1, it may be different in Spark 2.2 because the optimizer changed in Spark 2.2 (Cost-Based Optimizer)

Answer (score 1):

No, `dropDuplicates` doesn't preserve partitions since it has a shuffle boundary, which doesn't guarantee order.

`dropDuplicates` is approximately:

```
ds.groupBy(columnId).agg(/* take first column from any available partition */)
```

Comment: I don't think thats true, please check the physical plan

Comment: @RaphaelRoth It might not be in this particular case, but it should be noted that `dropDuplicates` will generally cause a shuffle to occur, and I wouldn't relay on an explicit repartitioning happening in real code.